# Project Reactor: How to delay emission of (throttle) each element?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

Consider the following `Flux`

```
Flux.range(1, 5)
  .parallel(10)
  .runOn(Schedulers.parallel())
  .map(i -> "https://www.google.com")
  .flatMap(uri -> Mono.fromCallable(new HttpGetTask(httpClient, uri)))
```

`HttpGetTask` is a Callable whose actual implementation is irrelevant in this case, it makes a HTTP GET call to the given URI and returns the content if successful.

Now, I'd like to slow down the emission by introducing an artificial delay, such that up to 10 threads are **started simultaneously**, but each one doesn't complete as soon as `HttpGetTask` is done. For example, say **no thread must finish before 3 seconds**. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If the requirement is really "not less than 3s" you could add a delay of 3 seconds to the `Mono` inside the `flatMap` by using `Mono.fromCallable(...).delayElement(Duration.ofSeconds(3))`.